# error 404 but app is successfully deployed

Tags: solution-package, 404

I have deployed a solution containing a REST web service.
When I recall the url I get error 404.

What could be wrong?
In the Central Admin I have the following properties

```
Name: MySharePointSolution.wsp
Type: Core Solution 
Contains Web Application Resource: No 
Contains Global Assembly: Yes 
Contains Code Access Security Policy: No 
Deployment Server Type: Front-end Web server 
Deployment Status: Deployed 
Deployed To: Globally deployed. 
Last Operation Result: The solution was successfully deployed. 
Last Operation Details: SHPAPP : The solution was successfully deployed. 
SHPFC : The solution was successfully deployed. 

Last Operation Time: 8/25/2014 11:55 AM
```

Maybe, Contains Web Application Resource should be yes?

The solution was installed with:

```
 Install-SPSolution –Identity MySharePointSolution.wsp –GACDeployment
```

instead of:

```
Install-SPSolution –Identity MySharePointSolution.wsp –WebApplication
http://myspwebapp –GACDeployment
```

Comment: same issue, my site on my front-ends and content server are now down with same issue.